# Django using functions from a python class from frontend?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, neo4j

I am new to Django, but i managed to create the back-end and front end for my website but in the front end i am connecting to an external socket and getting data on the fly and i implemented a class that has the function `add_data2GraphDB(Data)` that adds the element to my graph database

How can I call this function from the front end so it is applied in the back-end without disturbing the rendering of the website.

this is the js code on the front-end page

```
<script>
eventToListenTo = 'tx'
room = 'inv'

var socket = io("https://blockexplorer.com/");
socket.on('connect', function() {
  // Join the room.
  socket.emit('subscribe', room);
})

socket.on(eventToListenTo, function(data) {

***add_data2GraphDB(Data)***;
})
</script>
```

also after getting the Data i am viewing it in to the user with ability to check the details of this data so it should be added to the graph before viewing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using ajax and also @Ehvince helped me with the concept of the api 
basically in the front-end i used:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/app/add2Graph/',
    data:{
        tx:data.txid,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
    },
    success:function(result){
    console.log(result)
    }
});
```

and in the back-end I added the URL

```
url(r'^app/add2Graph/$',addTx2graph, name='add2graph'),
```

and in the api I added:

```
def addTx2graph(request):
transactionInfo="Unknown transaction" 
if request.method=='POST':
    tx=request.POST['tx']
    transactionInfo=addTransaction(tx)
return HttpResponse("success")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start providing an api point to your Django app that will take parameters from the request body (or/and request parameters) and call your function. So create an url like `/api/add2grah`. And you call it in the front end with a classic async call.

Now if your function takes a long time, you may want to start using a task queue, so than your api function returns immediately but your add2Graph runs in the back. Good and simple solutions are [Huey](https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html), [Django-q](https://django-q.readthedocs.io) or django-rq (they're simpler than Celery).

Does that answer something ?

Comment: but isn't that if i called the api by URLs i will have to redirect to get back to the page on each function call 
like on each element of data i receive i will have to go to the /api/add2graph and then redirect to the Homepage
correct me if i am mistaken

Comment: Looks like you are mistaken. When you go to an url on the Django side, you redirect the user. On the JS side, you don't redirect unless you change the `window.location` variable (or stuff). That's why we can make many async API calls in a JS app.

Comment: so just to be sure i call the function add2graph from the views or from the url directly reference it @Ehvince